# how to run web service (WSDD file) from cmd?

Tags: java, web-services, cmd, axis, noclassdeffounderror

[image]

am trying to run wsdd file from cmd , but am having this error in the pic above. Its seems that the wsdd is not seeing the main class in the Sample.java file knowing that its in the working directory can anyone help plz

Comment: wsdd (web service description language) ,its a web service!

Comment: What's your question? If you want to run a Java class, you should use class name, Sample, not class file name, Sample.class.

Comment: i am doing that right now but it still giving me the same error!

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError or no main in class? What do you want? Deploy a webservice using WSDD?

Comment: am trying to call a web service using the following commad :

java -Daxis.ClientConfigFile=SampleDeploy.wsdd Sample.class

Comment: So you have already deployed the webservice? I think WSDD is used to deploy a webservice.

Comment: yes the web service is working fine and am trying to call it here but its giving me the error above any idea ??

Comment: I suppose you are using AXIS. Check the user guide: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#CustomDeploymentIntroducingWSDD. And I don't think we can call a web service using WSDD. You need to get the WSDL and generate some Java stubs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the JVM didnt know were to look for the class , so i had to set the classPath to the location of the desired class so the JVM can run it. hope this would help someone else

Comment: How do you invoke the webservice? Could you please show me? Thanks.

Comment: java -Daxis.ClientConfigFile=SampleDeploy.wsdd Sample , but you need to set the CLASSPATH before so the JVM can find your classes and JARS